# How to replace standard bootstrap table with dataTables in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datatables

I have tried and searching lot of solution but not solve my problem, even at dataTables website. The problem is how to display nested array in json using DataTables? Fo example below, How if I just want to display `l3_id: "1"` data only.

I try to understand this link but not really understand. [Example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html)

There is no error at console and network tab.

DataTable not appear, including dataTables features such as search box, pagination. (The CDN/library has been imported)
[image]

**JSON**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "project_id": "1",
            "l1_task": [
                {
                    "l1_id": "1",
                    "l2_task": [
                        {
                            "l2_id": "1",
                            "l3_task": [
                                {
                                    "l3_id": "1",
                                    "l3_name": "My name"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**JS (I am applying HTML in JS)**

```
"<table id='Layer3Table' class='table dt-responsive nowrap' style='width:100%'>"+
    "<thead>"+
        "<tr>"+
            "<th class='text-center'>ID</th>"+
            "<th class='text-center'>Activity Name</th>"+
        "</tr>"+
    "</thead>"+
"</table>"+

$('#Layer3Table').DataTable({
    ajax: { 
        url: url_project_detail",
        dataSrc : "data"
    },
    columns: [
        { data : "l1_task.0.l2_task.0.l3_task.0.l3_id" },
        { data : "l1_task.0.l2_task.0.l3_task.0.l3_name" },
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either define your table, including all `tbody` content in HTML, then use DataTables to enable the search etc features. If you do it this way you don't need to set the url or columns (although you can still set other options).

```js
$('#Layer3Table').DataTable();
```

Or if you want to make use of the url and column features, create the basic table structure in HTML

```html
<table id='Layer3Table' class='table dt-responsive nowrap' style='width:100%'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='text-center'>Project ID</th>
            <th class='text-center'>Project Name</th>
            <th class='text-center'>Project Description</th>
            <th class='text-center'>Project Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then set up your DataTable separately in JavaScript.

```js
$('#Layer3Table').DataTable( {
    ajax: { 
        url: url_project_detail,
        crossDomain : true,
        type : "POST",
        cache : false,
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataSrc : "data",
    },
    columns: [
        { data : "l3_id", "className": "text-center" },
        { data : "l3_name", "className": "text-center" },
        { data : "l3_description", "className": "text-center" },
        { data : "l3_status", "className": "text-center" }
    ],
});
```

What you appear to be doing is looping over your results and creating a DataTable for each of them, which is why it doesn't understand.

Comment: I have tried your second option but I put the HTML in JS like my post above and use dataTables in JS (as your suggestion). So I am not using <tbody>. However, the content in <thead> is appear in UI but the data not appear, No error at console log.

Comment: Just to inform that I have multiple nested array in json. for example `data: ['l1_task : ']['l2_task : ']['l3_task : ']` after that then will reach `[{l3_id, l3_name, l3_description......}]`

Comment: I think you need to either name the array that you want DataTables to use as `"data"` [as it is in this example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) (click on the Ajax tab below the table), or set the source using the `dataSrc` property in the ajax object in the DataTables settings - [example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html).

Comment: I have try both, but not solving. :-(

Comment: @mastersuse Can you update the question with how you have defined the dataSrc and a sample of the data returned (change sensitive details if need be)? Also check that you are actually receiving a response from the server, and in the manner you expect. Have the browser console open and select the Network tab. Trigger a DataTables request (reload page, click button or whatever), look for the Ajax request URL in the Network tab, select it and in the response on the right should be your JSON data.